# Sending a email message having HTML tags via PHPMailer using PHP heredoc feature

Tags: php, html, email

When a user fills out a contact form, I want the user to get an HTML message with a image at the start of message and some styling for a box with shadow in which the user's name and phone
number are shown.

I tried using $mail->IsHTML(true) and $mail->msgHTML($message) using PHPmailer but the message was not sent.

The message is below:

```
$message = <<<STARTMESSAGE

     <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
     <link href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>    

     <style type='text/css'>

        .box {
                margin: 40px;


                -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);


                display: block;
        }

        .content {
            position:relative;
            padding:100px;
            background-color:FFF;
        }

        .h3 {
            text-align:center;
            color:#008800;
        }
     </style>



        <img src='./img/logo.png' class='img-responsive center-block' alt='My website'>

    <h3> Contact Form Submission </h3>

     <div class='box'>
        <div class='content'>

    The following information was submitted: <br/> <br/>



    <strong>Full Name:</strong> $firstname $lastname <br/> <br/>
    <strong>Phone number:</strong> $phone  <br/> <br/>
     </div>
       </div>
STARTMESSAGE;
```

Edit:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($from , "Contact Form");
$mail->addAddress('myemail@example.org', "John Doe");

$mail->Subject = "Contact Form submission ".$name;


$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $message;

//$mail->msgHTML($message);

$mailsent = $mail->send();

if (!$mailsent)
    {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            error_log("Mail not sent for $firstname $lastname $mail->ErrorInfo \n", 1, "myemail@example.org");
            error_log("Message text is  $message \n", 1, "myemail@example.org");
            error_log("Value of variables from POST method $post_variables \n ", 1, "myemail@example.org");
            error_log("\n Value of variables from POST method $post_variables \n", 3, "logfile.txt");
            $logfile = fopen("errorlog.log","w+") or die("cannot open log file");
            fwrite($logfile,"Mail not sent for $firstname $lastname");
            $backtrace = debug_print_backtrace();
            fwrite($logfile,"Back trace is \n");
            fwrite($logfile,$backtrace);

    }
    else
    {
            echo "Message sent!";
            error_log("\n Mail sent for $firstname $lastname at $date \n", 3, "logfile.txt");
            error_log("\n Value of variables from POST method $post_variables \n", 3, "logfile.txt");                               
            header('Location: http://www.example.org/index.php?success=yes');               
    }
```

Comment: FYI: Most mail clients will reject/ignore stylesheets / <style>, and js linked files. Plus, you need to show more relevant code. Also, your img src needs to be a full http call, not a local file. Heredoc also requires a carriage return after its closing identifier. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Further to Fred-ii's comments, all styling for HTML emails must be inline, like this: `<h1 style="color:red;font-size:28px;">M E M O</h1>`

Comment: @gibberish True, which I meant to add in my comment originally but didn't have time to edit.

Comment: Fred, thanks for your comments. Heredoc has a carriage return after its closing identifier. I tried using the img src as a full http call but that also does not work.  I will try inline styling as gibberish suggested as the js and stylesheets could be the issue.

Comment: Gibberish, Thanks. I will try inline styling.

Comment: either way, it should still be "sending" the email but throwing out the linked files. Something else is causing this and you need to post more relevant code.

Comment: Just so you know, I tested it with my version and got the email back. I asked you twice to post your full already but you failed to do that. So, I won't be able to help you without knowing what that is and how it's used. Good luck. Edit: I'm betting you didn't use `$mail->Body    = ($message);` which is probably why. So let me know if you want this posted as an answer. @ChrisH Because I'm willing to bet my bottom dollar on it *lol*

Comment: and if that doesn't work ^ then your settings are incorrect. Again; no idea what your code looks like.

Comment: Yes post your whole code so that will help more just as @Fred-ii- said..!

Comment: @Fred, Thanks for posting back. I have added the remaining code which sends out the email. That did not change. Only the message contents changed since I tried to add HTML styling so I initially only posted that. Do you think someone whose messages were working would skip something like $mail->Body = $message; and expect it to work? I am new to using HTML styling in PHPmailer not using PHPmailer. Thanks for your time and posts.

Comment: @ChrisH I can't see this failing as I've tested it myself. If your `$message` heredoc isn't in the right spot, then that could be the reason. Check for errors also, you may have some. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php in case your heredoc has erroneous spaces etc. You'll need to edit your question again as to the "exact" placement of the heredoc.

Comment: @Fred, Thanks for posting back. The sending mail server had a restriction on attachment size. This wasn't the case last week so I did not know about it. Someone changed it and forgot to tell the folks who use it. That was causing the emails to be not sent. Again, thanks for all your time and posts.

Comment: @Fred, Also, using the img src as a full http call did not work for me. I had to use: $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("img/logo.png", "logo", "img/logo.png");
$mail->Body = 'My Logo: <img alt="Logo" src="cid:logo">

Comment: @ChrisH I'm glad to hear it was resolved and thanks for the update, *cheers*. If you are able, you can delete the question, or post an answer of your own if it doesn't let you delete it.

Comment: @ChrisH ah ok (about the img thing). Well, I feel you should be posting an answer for it. I'm pretty sure it could serve others and outlining everything that you need to do in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @Fred, I should mark your answer as correct since you spent so much time helping me, but since you commented, I don't know if I can mark it as an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisH I'll put something together, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @ChrisH You're welcome Chris, I'm glad it got resolved. My answer has been posted, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in comments:

Most mail clients will reject/ignore stylesheets / `<style>`, and JS linked files.

It's best not to use any JS and use an inline CSS method for styling.

An example of this was left in comments by [gibberish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447509/gibberish)

```
<h1 style="color:red;font-size:28px;">M E M O</h1>
```

As you also noted in comments:

> *@Fred, Thanks for posting back. The sending mail server had a restriction on attachment size. This wasn't the case last week so I did not know about it. Someone changed it and forgot to tell the folks who use it. That was causing the emails to be not sent. Again, thanks for all your time and posts. – Chris H*

and

> *@Fred, Also, using the img src as a full http call did not work for me. I had to use: $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("img/logo.png", "logo", "img/logo.png"); $mail->Body = 'My Logo:  – Chris H*

This for future readers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("img/logo.png", "logo", "img/logo.png");
$mail->Body = 'My Logo: <img alt="Logo" src="cid:logo">
```

to embed a image, in addition to using inline CSS.

However, I had an attachment size limitation at the sending mail server which was preventing the emails from being sent. This wasn't the case last week so I did not know about it earlier. Someone changed it and forgot to tell the folks who use it. That was blocking the emails from being sent.  If someone is using PHPMailer to send HTML emails, please ensure you are using

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $message;
```

where $message has contents of your message. Also, as Fred remarked scripts are removed by most email clients so inline CSS styling is needed.

Comment: Thanks Fred, It is people like you which make Stackoverflow the go to place for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue before few days.Then I put **inline css** instead of internal css and it worked fine.

You do the same(**put inline css**),it will work.

Comment: Thanks Suman, I tried that but the issue was a mail server attachment size restriction.

Comment: @ChrisH Good to know that :) Keep coding.